# How can I isolate the exceeding characters from a list and count them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to take lists such as 12345 and 1234567 and the output to be ['6', '7'] and then output the amount of characters in that list so [2]. I do not want it to just tell me the differences though I want to take a list such as 45454 and 4545 and still output [4].Below is the code I am using to compare lists 1 by 1 and then giving me a output of "-" if they are not the same.

```
word = input("Enter A Word: ")
list_1 = (word)


word = input("Enter A Word: ")
list_2 = (word)

lists_compared = [x if x==y else "-" for (x,y) in zip(list_1, list_2)]

print(lists_compared)
#%%
string = lists_compared
print(string.count("-"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip` only runs to the length of the shortest of the two lists. If you want to capture the full length of the longest of the two, use `zip_longest` .

First,

`import itertools`

then  replace the `lists_compared` line as follows

`lists_compared = [x if x == y else "-" for (x, y) in itertools.zip_longest(list_1, list_2)]`

Comment: Yes. The 'missing'  elements from the shorter list are padded out with None.

Answer (score 0):

If, like your examples, one list is always a continuation of the other, you can use this:

```
b[len(a):] if len(a) < len(b) else a[len(b):]
```

examples:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b[len(a):] if len(a) < len(b) else a[len(b):]
[3, 4, 5]

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b[len(a):] if len(a) < len(b) else a[len(b):]
[6, 7]
```